# Splitting string that has \u inside

Tags: python, string, unicode, split

I know that u"string" refers to Unicode. If I am not mistaken this is where I ran into a problem. I was not able to find a solution that ultimately helps me to split the string into 2 strings if that string has '\u' inside.

I have a list of strings that are divided by ',' where the first part is the crime committed and the second part is the location where the crime was committed.

for example:

```
SHOPLIFT, NE MILL PL 

VANDALISM, 136TH AVE NE 

SUSPICIOUS CIRCUMSTANCES, GARDEN WAY 

MENTAL PROBLEMS, NE WOODINVILLE DUVALL RD 

TRESPASS – 19200 BLK 168TH AVE NE
```

when I use the data.split(',')i get the following results:

```
[u'SHOPLIFT', u' NE MILL PL ']

[u'VANDALISM', u' 136TH AVE NE ']

[u'SUSPICIOUS CIRCUMSTANCES', u' GARDEN WAY ']

[u'MENTAL PROBLEMS', u' NE WOODINVILLE DUVALL RD ']

[u'TRESPASS \u2013 19200 BLK 168TH AVE NE ']
```

as you can see the split method worked fine for the first 4 items. The fifth item:

```
[u'TRESPASS \u2013 19200 BLK 168TH AVE NE ']
```

is the one I have the problem with.

How can I split that item so it would show the following:

```
[u'TRESPASS', u'2013 19200 BLK 168TH AVE NE ']
```

split('–') does not work either

```
 TRESPASS – 19200 BLK 168TH AVE NE
```

gives the following error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread and properly format your question and code. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `\u` with `, u'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That \u2013 that you see is telling you "this is unicode character 2013" (which happens to be a long dash).  You can see that after the "trespass" in your original printed string.  It sounds like you want to split the string based on EITHER a comma or that long dash.

One solution would be to convert the long dash to a comma, then split on the comma:

```
data.replace(u'\u2013',',').split(',')
```

A second solution would be to use `re.split()`

```
import re
re.split(u"[\,\u2013]", data)
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris Curvey. I was so focused on the \u part that I did not realize that I should be looking at the whole "\u2013". Much appreciate for your answer. you literally just saved the day.